# "Fanatic" badge streak disrupted - Why was login via GitHub disabled yesterday? Is there a chance to recover the streak?

Tags: support

As stated in the title, login via GitHub was not available yesterday.
I'm working towards a [Fanatic Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic) and was technically unable to fullfil the task.

I'm asking just in case someone else is affected: Can perhaps a moderator recover it (my guess is **no**) and more importantly does anybody know why login via GitHub was unavailable? Is that something that occurs regularly?

Comment: I can't address the real question here, but just in case it's helpful to a future reader: I do seem to remember that just visiting a stack's page isn't enough to trigger the day counter; you have to actively view a question in order to do that.

Comment: Visiting one's profile is considered enough of action to increase the streak.

Comment: I'm not sure if the fanatic badge really means much if you're just going through the motions to get it just for the sake of having it. I earned the fanatic badge without trying because I was drawn to the site every day. If you love music and appreciate this stack, you'll rack up the badges without having to think about it. If not... I can't see why you'd care about them in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing some questions:

> Can perhaps a moderator recover [the streak]?

No, moderators cannot recover this nor the badge.

> Why was login via GitHub unavailable?

According to [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341163/cannot-log-in-to-the-stack-exchange-android-app-with-a-github-login?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1141186_341163) (Stack Exchange staff), GitHub login is only available on Stack Overflow.

> That's an old question, referring to a user that was logging in with GitHub OpenID. We do now officially support GitHub OAuth logins on Stack Overflow. [...]

Outside of Stack Overflow, the only available login is email address, Google, and/or Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Interestingly enough, login on music _is_ possible via GitHub (that's how I login). There must've been a temporary disruption.

Comment: @s-gbz the fact that the SE staff says its only available on SO means that login you are using may be working by accident here. It may be worth it to ask more about that login flow on Meta SE.

Answer (score 0):

Consider contacting the [SO support](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) if you have longer term login trouble.

Reference: [Can't Login to Stack Overflow using Github](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306721/cant-login-to-stack-overflow-using-github)